# No backshift to maintain time relation between two clauses

Tags: reported-speech

The seller told  me :" Just after you **had paid** another man **asked** for it."

He told me that just after I had paid, another man asked for it". 
No backshift here to maintain the time relation between both verbs .Did I make the good choice?

Comment: I'd put one *more 'had'* for that asking.

Comment: but where will you put that" had " before asked or before" told "

Comment: When quoting a text or speech *verbatim* there is no shift.  You say exactly what was said.  It is only when you're reporting the speech that you become concerned about backshifts.  *The seller told me that just after **I had paid** ...*

Answer (score 1):

You might hear someone report this sequence of events in any of the following ways:

> The seller told me: "Just after you paid another man asked for it".
>
> The seller told me: "Just after you paid another man *had* asked for it".
>
> The seller told me: "Just after you *had* paid another man asked for it".
>
> The seller told me: "Just after you *had* paid another man *had* asked for it"

All make the sequence of events clear. I would opt for examples 1. (your choice) and 3. as preferable although you are likely to hear native English speakers using them all.